# Perl loop through text files in a directory, locate file based on file name and print content

Tags: perl

How do i loop through files in a directory, locate file based on file name and print file content?

Please see below code:
files in directory:

```
1234.txt
345.txt
234.txt
```

Code:

```
opendir (DIR, "LOCATION")|| die "cant open directory\n";

my @DATA = grep {(!/^\./)} readdir (DIR);
while ( my $file = shift @DATA) {
    open FILE, "LOCATION";
    while (FILE){
        if ($file eq "235") {
            print $_;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/faq before asking questions

Comment: Stack Overflow helps people with programming problems. You are expected to have made an attempt at this yourself and reached a programming problem that you can't resolve. We cannot be expected to write code for you for free.

Answer (score -1):

The code in your question:

```
opendir (DIR, "LOCATION")|| die "cant open directory\n";
my @DATA = grep {(!/^\./)} readdir (DIR);
while ( my $file = shift @DATA) {
    open FILE, "LOCATION";
    while (FILE){
        if ($file eq "235") {
            print $_;
        }
    }
}
```

Will do this:

First it will handily find all files in directory "LOCATION" that do not begin with a period. Then it will iterate in a rather odd loop over each file name. The normal version of this loop would be:

```
for my $file (@DATA)
```

Then it will attempt to open the directory "LOCATION" again. This will likely fail, because "LOCATION" is a directory. Since you do not check the return value with `die`, this error will be silent.

What you probably want is to use

```
if ($file eq "235.txt") {
    open my $fh, "<", $file or die $!;
    print <$fh>;
}
```

This part:

```
while (FILE)
```

Is not actually checking the return value of `readline()`, it is checking whether the file handle is returning a true value. As near as I can tell on my system, it does return a true value even if the `open` failed. Which means of course that the loop will run indefinitely. What you probably meant was

```
while (<FILE>)
```

However, as explained earlier, this will only result in the error "readline() on unopened file handle FILE" since the `open` statement cannot open a directory.

Your check

```
if ($file eq "235")
```

Will never be true, since you said your file names had a `.txt` extension. You might instead do

```
if ($file eq "235.txt")
```

Which should work.

If you wanted to be clever, you could include your check directly in the grep:

```
my @files = grep { $_ eq "235.txt" } readdir DIR;
```

And since perl can use the `<>` diamond operator to print files listed in the `@ARGV` array, you can even do this

```
@ARGV = grep { $_ eq "235.txt" } @ARGV;
print <>;
```

Assuming you call the script with:

```
perl script.pl dir/*.txt
```

This is, of course, just the long version of doing:

```
perl -pe0 235.txt
```

Which is the long version of

```
cat 235.txt
```

So, I get the feeling you are trying to do something other than what your code implies.

Answer (score -1):

This should do (untested):

```
opendir( DIR, "/path/to/dir" );
while ( my $entry = readdir( DIR ) ) {
    if ( $entry =~ /^$filenameImLookingFor$/ ) {
        open( FILE, "$entry/$filenameImLookingFor" );
        my @lines = <FILE>;
        close( FILE );
        print( join( '', @lines );
    }
}
closedir( DIR );
```